# Exercises with solutions on Elementary Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Where can I find a nice collection of solved exercises on Elementary Measure Theory? (Rings, algebras, $\sigma$-algebras, Borel sets, measures, outer measures, Lebesgue measure, measurable functions, Borel functions, etc.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. *René Schilling: Measures, Integrals and Martingales*. There is a [solution manual](http://motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/index.shtml) available on the web with full solutions to all exercises. The book does not only cover elementary measure theory, but further topics in measure/probability theory.
2. *Claude George: Exercises in Integration*. This is a problem book on measure theory; solutions to the exercises are included in the book ([table of contents](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-1-4684-6320-0%2F1.pdf)).

Comment: Schilling is my professor ).

Comment: Was his measure theory exam hard? Lol