# Exercises for "Probability with Martingales" by Williams (1991)

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Does anybody know some good exercises to supplement "Probability with Martingales" by Williams (1991)?
I really like the book, but I feel I need more exercises to train with. Ideally, I am looking for a course based on that book with available assignments and solutions.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I think references in these posts may help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673279/suggestion-on-a-book-on-measure-theory & https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534235/exercises-with-solutions-on-elementary-measure-theory. I do not know all references, but I followed a course based on the book of Schilling, which I thought was nicely written :)

Comment: That is helpful, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @delivery101 gasp! those don't mention rosenthal's A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grimmett and Stirzaker's Probability and Random Processes (and is paired with a solution book) is a great choice. I keep returning to it for interesting exercises.

Comment: what is your opinion of rosenthal's A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory?